# Annotation to get value of another annotation

Tags: java, string

In spring boot 3 I have many controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/queries")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class QueriesController {

 @ToTake
 @PutMapping("/{id}")
 ....

}
```

If i create annotation to take, is it possible to get value of the RequestMapping and PutMapping annotation?

Comment: Are you going to handle annotation manually via Reflection? In such case If yes, then all the power is available to you and you can get all annotation both from same method and its class

Answer (score 0):

Annotations is just for metadata purpose, so you can't assign work to it. If you wish you can use it as marker for search in the Spring context:

```
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    ...
    ...
    
var beanNames = applicationContext.getBeanNamesForAnnotation(ToTake.class);
for(String beanName : beanNames) {
  Object bean = applicationContext.getBean(beanName);
  Class<?> clazz = bean.getClass();

  if(clazz.isAnnotationPresent(RestController.class)) {
    RestController annotation = clazz.getAnnotation(RestController.class);
    System.out.println(annotation.value());
  }

  for(Method method : clazz.getMethods()) {
    if(method.isAnnotationPresent(PutMapping.class)) {
      PutMapping annotation = method.getAnnotation(PutMapping.class);
      System.out.println(annotation.value());
    }
  }
}
```

You should note that `applicationContext.getBean(beanName);` will trigger resolving bean according its scope and proxy mode.

You're also able to use any classpath scanning libs for searching for annotation at runtime, or to use list of classes known at compile time